# Failing to manage multiple windows and save data in a survey's GUI with R and gWidgets

Tags: r, user-interface, survey, gwidgets

I recently started using R and find myself blocked while trying to build a graphical user interface.

My aim is **to code a GUI for the conduction of a survey**. Basically, I would like to open a window composed of a question, an answer and a *Next* button. Upon cliking on *Next* I wish to **save the answer and jump to the next window/question**.

---

As I had problems opening several windows I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455692/how-to-return-values-from-gwidgets-and-handlers) and found it was possible to open windows one after the other with the help of a handler:

```
addHandlerChanged() #upon the Next button
```

So I tried to input a code (see below) for two questions/windows.
I thought to save the results in *to_return*: a matrix 2 rows (1, 2) and 3 columns  (Question number, Question, Answer). [I am now trying to write answers question after question in an excel file]

My problem is as follows:

1. **I fail to close the first window** after opening the second (I
   tried adding *dispose(h$obj)* or *visible(win1)=FALSE* to the the first
   windows button handler but it fails)
2. **I fail to "apend" data** to my matrix (the *to_return* matrix is
       renewed with every window)

```
# calling GUI library
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="tcltk")

Q1 <- function(){
  # creating first window
  win1 <- gwindow("I) Q1.", visible=TRUE)
  group <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=win1)
  # creating question
  question <- glabel("Do you have a driving license?", container = group)
  # creating answer
  answer <- gradio(c("Yes","No"), container=group)
  # creating next button
  nextQuestion <- gbutton("Next",container=group)
  # handler
  addHandlerChanged(nextQuestion, handler = function(h, ...) {
    # answer to save in matrix
    to_return <- rbind(to_return,c(svalue(win1),svalue(question),svalue(answer)))
    #opening next question
    Q2()
    print(to_return)
  } )
}


Q2<- function(){
  # creating second window
  win2 <- gwindow("I) Q2.", visible=TRUE)
  group <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=win2)
  # creating question
  question <- glabel("What is your gender?", container = group)
  # creating answer
  answer <- gradio(c("Female","Male"), container=group)
  # finish button
  nextQuestion <- gbutton("Finish",container=group, handler = function(h,...) {
    # answer to save in matrix
    to_return <- rbind(to_return,c(svalue(win2),svalue(question),svalue(answer)))
    print(to_return)
    # finish and close
    dispose(h$obj)
  })
}
```

If I run *Q1()* I get the following results where *to_return* doens't keep the data...

```
     [,1]     [,2]                             [,3] 
[1,] "I) Q1." "Do you have a driving license?" "Yes"
     [,1]     [,2]                   [,3]    
[1,] "I) Q2." "What is your gender?" "Female"
```

Any help or insight will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Octave

---

EDIT : Following the answer of jverzani, here is a possible code for two questions with data saving in csv file.

```
## calling GUI library
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="tcltk")

setwd("Your\\Path\\Here")

w <- gwindow(title="Survey")
g <- ggroup(cont=w)

state = new.env()
pages <- list()
pages[[1]] = function(cont, state) {
  group <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=cont)
  ## creating question
  question <- glabel("Do you have a driving license?", container = group)
  ## creating answer
  answer <- gradio(c("Yes","No"), container=group)
  ## creating next button
  nextQuestion <- gbutton("Next",container=group)
  ## handler
  addHandlerChanged(nextQuestion, handler = function(h, ...) {
    ## answer to save in matrix
    assign("A", c(svalue(question),svalue(answer)), state)
    delete(cont, group)
    pages[[2]](cont, state)
  })
}

pages[[2]] = function(cont, state) {
  group <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=cont)
  ## creating question
  question <- glabel("What is your gender?", container = group)
  ## creating answer
  answer <- gradio(c("Male","Female", "Other"), container=group)
  ## creating next button
  nextQuestion <- gbutton("Next",container=group)
  ## handler
  addHandlerChanged(nextQuestion, handler = function(h, ...) {
    ## answer to save in matrix
    assign("B", c(svalue(question),svalue(answer)), state)
    delete(cont, group)
    pages[[3]](cont, state)
  })
}

pages[[3]] = function(cont, state) {
  group <- ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, container=cont)
  ## result matrix for csv
  to_return=matrix(nrow=0,ncol=2)
  colnames(to_return) <- c("Question", "Answer")
  for (k in 1:length(names(state))) {
    a = get(names(state)[k], state)
    to_return <- rbind(to_return,a)
    rownames(to_return)[k] <- paste("Q",k,sep = "")
    g = ggroup(cont=group, horizontal=TRUE)
    glabel(a[1], cont=g)
    glabel(" ", cont=g)
    glabel(a[2], cont=g)
  }
  btn <- gbutton("Finish", container=group, handler = function(h,...) {
    write.csv(to_return, "survey.csv", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)
    dispose(h$obj)})
}

## start it off
pages[[1]](g, state)
```

EDIT 2: the line assign("one", c(svalue(question),svalue(answer)), state) should use alphabetical letters ("A", "B"...) or numbers in the right order otherwise answers get mixed up when using for k in names(state).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most abstracted, but this pattern using `delete` over new windows, should be easily understood for subsequent modification. The use of an environment helps you keep state between calls to a handler, which won't be the case without some such trick, as assignments will be made within the environment of the handler by default.

```
# calling GUI library
library(gWidgets2)
options(guiToolkit="tcltk")


w <- gwindow()
g <- ggroup(cont=w)

state = new.env()
pages <- list()
pages[[1]] = function(cont, state) {
    group <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=cont)
    ## creating question
    question <- glabel("Do you have a driving license?", container = group)
    ## creating answer
    answer <- gradio(c("Yes","No"), container=group)
    ## creating next button
    nextQuestion <- gbutton("Next",container=group)
    ## handler
    addHandlerChanged(nextQuestion, handler = function(h, ...) {
        ## answer to save in matrix
        assign("one", c(svalue(question),svalue(answer)), state)
        delete(cont, group)
       pages[[2]](cont, state)
    })
}

pages[[2]] = function(cont, state) {
    group <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=cont)
    ## creating question
    question <- glabel("What is your gender?", container = group)
    ## creating answer
    answer <- gradio(c("Male","Female", "Other"), container=group)
    ## creating next button
    nextQuestion <- gbutton("Next",container=group)
    ## handler
    addHandlerChanged(nextQuestion, handler = function(h, ...) {
        ## answer to save in matrix
        assign("two", c(svalue(question),svalue(answer)), state)
        delete(cont, group)
        pages[[3]](cont, state)
    })
}

pages[[3]] = function(cont, state) {
    group <- ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, container=cont)
    for (k in names(state)) {
        g = ggroup(cont=group, horizontal=TRUE)
        a = get(k, state)
        glabel(a[1], cont=g)
        glabel(" ", cont=g)
        glabel(a[2], cont=g)
    }
}

## start it off
pages[[1]](g, state)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Everything works and I'll try to look deeper into new.environment() and handler() functions to understand how everything goes.
If I understand it correctly, here we only create one window and update the groups shown in this window?
However, when I try to input a size in the preliminary window w, it doesn't affect the way windows are displayed afterwards... Is the size recalculated with each group shown in the window?

Comment: That is toolkit dependent. I forget about tcltk. But you may need to call size. That isn’t necessary for your problem, but I’m not a fan of new windows, so added it.